# Inclusive search in vim

Tags: vim

I remarked that when I search for a pattern with / in vim, the cursor is sent to the next occurence of the pattern, even if the cursor was on an occurence before the search. How can I search for a pattern and have the cursor be still if it is already on an occurence ?

One can avoid the problem by setting wrapscan and using N, but is there an easier way ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With incremental search enabled (via `set incsearch`), the next match is highlighted as you type but the cursor is actually moved *only* when you hit `<CR>`. Pressing `<Esc>` at any time cancels the search and you are back were you started.